# What is meant by, "But I suppose a mother does"?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, justice-league-2017

In the movie *Justice League (2017)*, Martha Kent, who has lost her son Superman, says to journalist Lois Lane:

> Well, I can hardly read the news, anyway. So much bitterness. Of
>   course I think it's all because he's gone. **But I suppose a mother
>   does**. But it's not like there's any less that needs reporting.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with Justice League or sci fi and fantasy in particular, and seems to be more a language issue

Comment: This is actually quite poignant. Martha comments on the state of the world being worse off since Kal's death. She passes it off as the 'lamentations of a mother', but in reality, it's supposed to be true, the world _is_ more messed for this lacking. Such was Bruce Wayne's point.

Comment: Just as @Au101 says.  Basically "I suppose a mother does....." is short for the phrase "I suppose a mother does think that way..."  It's just part of the precious setence - simply, imagine a comma there rather than a fullstop. That's all it is.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The implication is that, of course a mother would think the problem stems from the disappearance of her child or is in some way related. You could read this same quote like this:

> Well, I can hardly read the news, anyway. So much bitterness. Of course I think *all this bitterness* is because he's gone. But I suppose a mother *would think that*. But it's not like there's any less that needs reporting.

Imagine if a child was hit by a car and killed. The whole street would likely start acting differently, and probably more subdued as you see fewer and fewer children playing outside. A mother (and most others, honestly, but mostly a mother) would think that the act that took her child's life would be responsible for the shift. Thats what Martha Kent is saying, she thinks the shift in the news is a result of what happened to Superman, then she qualifies that statement with "but I suppose a mother does [think that]".

Comment: Alternate side same coin - Mom can't read journalism without thinking of her lost son and being bitter about it. Still a +1 though.

Comment: That last sentence is still weird. Maybe consider rephrasing it while you're at it?